# Multi-variable function is undefined at every point, then limit still may exist

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

The following question was posed;

If a multi-variable function $f(x,y)$ was undefined at every point on a curve, then could a limit exist of a point $(x_0, y_0)$ on this curve for this function? i.e Does $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x,_0, y_0)}f(x,y)$ exist?

To me, the whole point of limits is to find how functions behave when the function gets arbitrarily close to points where it is not defined. So, yes, I would think that regardless if a function $f(x,y)$ is undefined at a point, then a limit still could exist.

However, I can't think of an example of a function on a curve that is undefined for every point. So I'm beginning to think that if this question was stated that if $f(x,y)$ was undefined only at a certain point, then a limit could exist, which could be trivially proven by the definition. But because it says that **every point** on the curve is not defined, then no, the limit cannot exist for an arbitrary point $(x_0, y_0)$. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: Consider the function in polar coordinates $f(r,\phi)=(\phi-1)/(r-1)$. This is not defined on the unit sphere $S=\{(x,y)|r^2:=x^2+y^2=1\}$, but for $r=\phi\neq 1$ it holds that $f(r,\phi)=1$. Therefore with $(r_n,\phi_n)=(1+1/n,1+1/n)$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(r_n,\phi_n)=1$.

Comment: But if you were to define a particular subset like you did, then it isn't undefined at every x and y, is it? Couldn't we hypothetically define any subset that is only defined for some particular x and y values?

Comment: When i read curve i assumed you mean a one dimensional manifold which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is that not what the original question was about? If the function is not defined at each point of it's domain, the question makes no sense to me

Comment: Yes it's just a function $f(x,y)$. I was just wondering because it seemed that that this only worked for $r = x^2 + y^2 = 1$, and that isn't all the possible x and y values, right?

Comment: Sorry i think my last comment was unclear. If $f$ is undefined for every $x,y$, then expressions like $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n,y_n)$ do not make sense.

Comment: hello: You use the “function on a curve” very vaguely — what exactly do you mean by that? 
As @GregordeCillia mentioned, if you chose a function to be undefined in its whole domain, you cannot take limits becaus this would be the _empty function_ which does not contain any values.
That you say “…every point on the curve is not defined” Is rather paradox: First you stress that it is _every point_, but that you chose _curve_ points out that you mean any _arbitrary collection of points_ in the context. So where exactly shall the function be undefined now?